# No such module 'OneSignal' - XCode Swift Compiler Error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, onesignal

I'm currently trying to add OneSignal to my react native expo (bare) IOS build and have followed OneSignal's guide as shown here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup

However, Xcode has flagged up a compiler error of: **No such module 'OneSignal'**

[image: Compiler Error]

Here is my Podfile that includes the **OneSignalXCFramework** import:

```rb
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")

platform :ios, '12.0'

require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read('./Podfile.properties.json')) rescue {}

target '<NAME>' do
  use_expo_modules!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes'
  )

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!('Flipper' => '0.75.1', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1')
  # end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)

    # Workaround `Cycle inside FBReactNativeSpec` error for react-native 0.64
    # Reference: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/842#issuecomment-812543933
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if (target.name&.eql?('FBReactNativeSpec'))
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if (build_phase.respond_to?(:name) && build_phase.name.eql?('[CP-User] Generate Specs'))
            target.build_phases.move(build_phase, 0)
          end
        end
      end
    end
    
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    # some older pods don't support some architectures, anything over iOS 11 resolves that
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end

end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0', '< 4.0'
end
```

As a side note, I've already tried to add `pod 'OneSignal'` or `use_frameworks!` into the PodFile. Has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Comment: use SPM (Swift Package Manager) to install. https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/swift-package-manager-setup

Answer (score 11):

***Xcode 14.0.1 update & Swift 5.7 - Using SPM(Swift Package Manager)***

Recently I have integrated one signal into my project using SPM. it worked fine until I tried to upload the build to app store connect and it started showing me the same error. Here's how I fixed this issue.

***Step 1:***
Removed the one signal dependency

***Step 2:***
added again one signal Notification framework as a dependency.[image]

On the Choose package products popup.

1. Select OneSignal to add to the project as a target.
2. Select OneSignalExtension to be added to the oneSignalNotificationService extension as a target.
3. Now go to "NotificationService.swift" file in OneSignalNotificationExtension and replace > import Onesignal with >import OneSignalExtension.
4. Also replace oneSignal in code with OneSignalExtension.
5. Add Package and build.

Comment: In order to see both of the Package Products, you must be using https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK instead of https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-XCFramework

Comment: This was annoying and preventing me from distributing my app. Thank you!

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't update their setup documentation yet to mention this

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and use an Apple Silicon Mac i.e M1/M2 and the Pros, you would need to turn on Rosetta. To do this, in your Xcode menu, select Product > Destination > Destination Architectures > Show Rosetta Destinations. Build in Rosetta after running the following command:

`pod deintegrate && pod install`

Comment: finally it's worked!!

Comment: I don't see the option for the Destination Architectures in the Destination dropdown. I am using xcode version 14.2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, which may not be the reason for many of you but may help someone, the first time I've added it, all works well, but after merging the code into my main branch I get this error. My problem was that I have added `podfile` to `.gitignore` so it was working the first time but after merging it, podfile of course doesn't have the needed last section which is

```
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.0', '< 4.0'
end
```

So make sure you have it.